# CSS3 menu fadeOut not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu with a simple fade effect. It is working fine in chrome, when I leave my mouse and quickly move back my mouse in the dropdown remains on its place cause of the animation. However: in Firefox the animation `menuHoverFadeOut` is not working at all. So in firefox the animation makes no sense. I am using the following CSS code:

```
#cssmenu li > ul
{
  background: #005588;
  border: 1px solid #004477;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 5000;
  opacity:0;
  animation: menuHoverFadeOut 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: menuHoverFadeOut 0.5s ease-in-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
  animation-transition-property: opacity;
  top:-9999px;
}

#cssmenu li:hover > ul
{
  opacity:1;
  animation: menuHoverFadeIn 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-animation: menuHoverFadeIn 0.5s linear;
  top:auto;
}

@keyframes menuHoverFadeIn
{
    from {opacity:0;}to {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes menuHoverFadeIn
{
    from {opacity:0;}to {opacity:1;}
}

@keyframes menuHoverFadeOut {
    0%   {opacity:1;top:initial;}
    50%   {opacity:1;top:initial;}
    100% {opacity:0;top:-9999;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes menuHoverFadeOut
{
    0%   {opacity:1;top:initial;}
    50%   {opacity:1;top:initial;}
    100% {opacity:0;top:-9999;}
}
```

With the following HTML structure:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul id='main'>
   <li>Home
     <ul>
        <li>test1</li>
        <li>test2</li>
        <li>test3</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>About
     <ul>
        <li>test1</li>
        <li>test2</li>
        <li>test3</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I like to see it the way it works in chrome, I also tried it in transition however it didn't work properly in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/jgaFL/1/

Answer (score 1):

Provide browser specific prefix also for Firefox (and Opera):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes menuHoverFadeOut {
    /* ... */
}
@-moz-keyframes menuHoverFadeOut {
    /* ... */
}
@-o-keyframes menuHoverFadeOut {
    /* ... */
}
@keyframes menuHoverFadeOut {
    /* ... */
}

/* (...) */

#cssmenu li > ul {
    -webkit-animation: menuHoverFadeOut 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: menuHoverFadeOut 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: menuHoverFadeOut 0.5s ease-in-out;
    animation: menuHoverFadeOut 0.5s ease-in-out;
    /* ... and so on */
}
```

---

### **Anyway**,

I don't understand why bothering with `animation`. After egzamining the effect you're trying to achieve, I think its much simpler to use `transition`:

```css
-webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
```

Comment: I'd also suggest to add browser specific prefixes for opera as well:
@-o-keyframes menuHoverFadeOut {

Comment: and don't forget to add the browser prefixes where you're calling them: -moz-animation: menuHoverFadeOut 0.5s ease-in-out; /* Firefox */

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I am sorry but those solutions are not working :( The fadeIn is working great (even on firefox) but the fadeOut is only working at chrome(+other webkit browsers?). Beside that i am using firefox 27 wisch does not need -moz- prefix.

Its not about the animation but the effect that the dropdown menu stands for 0,5s if you leave you're mouse out of it (for user-friendliness).